# Migrating application from Delphi 7 to Delphi 2007 - problem with dbxint30.dll

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2007

We are migrating a server application from Delphi 7 to Delphi 2007 and having some problems with the dbxint30.dll.
I can test on my computer that has Delphi 2007 installed but on another computer.
I found something about this on Google regarding the version of DBExpress used by Delphi 7 and Delphi 2007 - but then, what could be the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Delphi 2007, the dbExpress driver dlls can [no longer be linked in to your executable](http://www.drbob42.com/examines/examin91.htm).  Have you tried deploying dbxint30.dll with your application?